# How can I dynamically add YES or NO CheckBoxes to a UserForm?

Tags: vba, excel

I’m loading a Useform, dynamically, in the following way.

```
Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Worksheets("SetupQuestions")
        Lrow = Worksheets("SetupQuestions").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngSource = .Range("A2:B" & Lrow)
    End With
    NewrngSource = Replace(rngSource.Address, "$", "")
                With ListBox1
                    .Value = "None"
                    .ColumnHeads = True
                    .ColumnCount = 2
                    .ColumnWidths = "50;100"
                    .RowSource = "SetupQuestions!" & NewrngSource & ""
                    .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
                    .BoundColumn = 1
                End With
End Sub
```

I’m trying to figure out a way to add CheckBoxes that correspond to the items in the ListBox.  I can easily get items from my ListBox.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim text As String
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
            text = text & Me.ListBox1.List(i, 0) & ". " & Me.ListBox1.List(i, 1) & " " & Chr(10)
        End If
    Next i
    Sheets("NEW Format").Range("BB1").Value = text
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

I just can’t figure out how to add CheckBoxes dynamically.  Here is a view of my Lisbox, and one CheckBox for the YES/NO objects, but I have only one listed here and I really want all CheckBoxes that correspond to every item in the list.

[image]

I saw one sample script online that looked promising, but it adds CheckBoxes UNDER my ListBox, and not to the right of it.

```
For Each rngCell In rngSource
    If rngCell.Value <> "" Then
        Set NewChkBx = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1")
        With NewChkBx
            .Caption = rngCell.Value
            .Left = 5
            .Top = TopPos
            .AutoSize = True
            If .Width > MaxWidth Then MaxWidth = .Width
        End With
        TopPos = TopPos + 15
    End If
Next rngCell
```

Comment: Have you tried playing with the Left setting as well as the Top?

Answer (score 0):

I'm it's possible to auto-generate CheckBoxes, but it was taking too long and I was running out of time for the thing I'm working on.  I ended up adding in some AND/OR fields in a column adjacent columns, and I added some code to handle everything correctly.

[image]

All set now.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

i'm giving an answer, even you don't need it anymore. Other people might look for it.

Here is an example code for creating 2 checkboxes in a userform :

```
Option Explicit 'inside userform's code

Private Sub AddCheckboxes()
Dim i&
For i=1 to 2
    with Me.controls.add("Forms.Checkbox.1","CheckBx" & i ,true) '3 arguments : the first is a fix one (do not mind the ".1" inside it, it is the way it needs to be ; the 2nd is the name of the control, the 3rd means visible=true
        .top=50 + (i-1)*20 'commencing at 50 and having a distance of 20 between controls
        .Left = 50
        .Caption= "Autorize or Do something as #" & i 'for example
    end with
next i
end sub
```

if having many controls, the best thing is putting them in an array of dictionary, and in my case i often use dictionary of calsses (the class havin many controls) , and like this i can make a common behaviour for all those controls, for example `_mousemove` or `_mousedown`...